# Sql String unequal Joins?

Tags: sql, oracle

These are my Tables:

```
MITARBEITER (mid, mname, abtid*)
PROJEKT (prjid, prjname, prjleiter*)
ARBEITSPAKETE (prjid, apid, apbezeichnung, umfangstd)
ARBEITET_AN (mid*, prjid*, apid*, anzahlstd)
ABTEILUNG (abtid, abtname)
```

I want to select all Names From my Mitarbeiter Table, who didnt work for the Projektname "Optimierung Einkauf".

This is my Sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MITARBEITER.mname
FROM MITARBEITER
JOIN ARBEITET_AN
ON MITARBEITER.MID = ARBEITET_AN.MID
JOIN ARBEITSPAKETE
ON ARBEITET_AN.prjid = ARBEITSPAKETE.prjid
JOIN PROJEKT
ON ARBEITSPAKETE.prjid = PROJEKT.prjid
where NOT (PROJEKT.prjname = 'Optimierung Einkauf') ;
```

i tried :

```
SELECT DISTINCT MITARBEITER.mname
FROM MITARBEITER
JOIN ARBEITET_AN
ON MITARBEITER.MID = ARBEITET_AN.MID
JOIN ARBEITSPAKETE
ON ARBEITET_AN.prjid = ARBEITSPAKETE.prjid
join PROJEKT
ON ARBEITSPAKETE.prjid = PROJEKT.prjid
where PROJEKT.prjname <> 'Optimierung Einkauf';
```

Why do i get Mitarbeiter who worked for the Projekt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT ma.mname
FROM MITARBEITER ma
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ARBEITET_AN a JOIN
                       ARBEITSPAKETE asp
                       ON a.prjid = asp.prjid JOIN 
                       PROJEKT p
                       ON asp.prjid = p.prjid
                  WHERE ma.MID = a.MID AND p.prjname = 'Optimierung Einkauf'
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Could u explain what the ...( Select 1 From Arbeitet_An) does? What does the 1 do ?

Comment: @Hansanho . . . That is a correlated subquery.  It checks if any rows from the subquery match.  Note the connection in the `WHERE` clause to the outer query.

Comment: Yes i got this. So the 1 gets returned if the Where clause matchs? Thanks Gordon you helped me alot and saved my time :D!!!

Comment: @Hansanho . . . `EXISTS` checks if any row is returned.  "1" is an arbitrary value that is easy to type and unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You could use anot in for all the name that work for the project you don't want

```
SELECT DISTINCT MITARBEITER.mname
FROM MITARBEITER
JOIN ARBEITET_AN ON MITARBEITER.MID = ARBEITET_AN.MID
JOIN ARBEITSPAKETE ON ARBEITET_AN.prjid = ARBEITSPAKETE.prjid
where MITARBEITER.mname not in (
    SELECT DISTINCT MITARBEITER.mname
    FROM MITARBEITER
    JOIN ARBEITET_AN ON MITARBEITER.MID = ARBEITET_AN.MID
    JOIN ARBEITSPAKETE ON ARBEITET_AN.prjid = ARBEITSPAKETE.prjid
    JOIN PROJEKT ON ARBEITSPAKETE.prjid = PROJEKT.prjid 
          and PROJEKT.prjname = 'Optimierung Einkauf' ;
)
```